# Largest Possible Font Size on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uifont

Is it possible to make a font larger than 300pt on iOS? If not, what are alternative approaches when dealing with UILabels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a font larger than 300pt. In storyboard, you need open it as source code and change the pointSize.

```
<fontDescription key="fontDescription" ... pointSize="400"/>
```

but why you need such a large font.

Comment: Ended up doing it in `viewDidLoad`. This is for use on an external display where the text needs to be as large as possible to fit the display size. Sometimes it is only showing a single digit.